# Can one build pipeline send a value as a parameter to the next pipeline it triggers in Azure DevOps

Tags: variables, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a build pipeline, lets say A - that stores a file (this file has a variable value that is set within that build pipeline) within a folder. This Pipeline A triggers another Pipeline B that Publishes the folder as an artifact using the Publish artifact task. But the folder name is dynamic as it is fetched from that file within Pipeline A. I need to pass on the file with that variable value from Pipeline A to Pipeline B while triggering it. Is there any way to do this in Azure DevOps, without using the yaml pipelines?

I have a little complex set of pipelines that I set up using the Classic mode, and converting them all to yaml would take a long time, so would like to know if there is any work around to this.

Comment: How do you trigger pipeline B from A?

Comment: By adding Pipeline A under the Triggers (Build Completion) section of Pipeline B.

Comment: The solution/workaround of Shayki is the better way. What's the result after you trying it?

Comment: What I did was, create a variable in Pipeline B. I tried to send the value of the variable from Pipeline A, by using the REST API call to queue Pipeline B with this variable as a parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a clean way to do this if you need to trigger the build by adding Pipeline A under the triggers section of Pipeline B.

Consider triggering Pipeline B when Pipeline A completes using the REST API. That way, you can have your 'file path' as a variable on Pipeline B and pass it in the `parameters` collection.

Something like:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?ignoreWarnings={ignoreWarnings}&checkInTicket={checkInTicket}&sourceBuildId={sourceBuildId}&api-version=5.0

{
    "definition": {
        "id": 1234
    },
    "parameters": "{\"fileName\":\"yourfilename\"}"
}
```

- filePath would be the name of your variable in Pipeline B

Have a look at the [Builds - Queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) documentation for more info.

Comment: yeah, i second this, I dont think you can really do that apart from forcefully triggering the other build with some variable or sending an api request from the started build to get some data about the completed build

Comment: Why not use an orchestrator like Azure logic apps ?

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to update everyone who will be checking this question, that the above solution is what I implemented, and it worked as well.

Answer (score 6):

There are few workarounds:

1. Create a variable group, and during the Pipeline A set the variable value there with [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/update), then Pipeline B use this variable.
2. During Pipeline A update the Pipeline B definition with the new value with [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update).
3. In Pipeline A trigger the Pipeline B with [Trigger Build Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks), there you can pass the variable value to the Pipeline B (you do it in the  "Build Parameters" field).

Comment: I do not have access to the Trigger Build Task that you have mentioned, but what I did was, create a variable in Pipeline B. I tried to send the value of the variable from Pipeline A, by using the REST API call to queue Pipeline B with this variable as a parameter. But am stuck in the curl command for it. :( For some reason, am not able to send the parameters object in the Request body. It accepts only build definition.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to Charlie's answer for version 7.1 of DevOps API you should use [this endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1):

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs?api-version=7.1-preview.1

{
    "templateParameters": {
        "yourParameterName": ""object:\r\n  'example':\r\n    in:\r\n    - yaml""
    }
}
```

To Auth you can use Basic Auth with any username string and [PAT Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows) as password.